# How to get an unbounded continuous output from a neural network?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am currently building a neural network to predict features such as temperature. So the output for this could be a positive or negative value. I am normalizing my input data and using the tanh activation function in each hidden layer.

Should I use a linear activation function for the output layer to get an unbounded continuous output OR should I use tanh for the output layer and then inverse normalize the output? Could someone explain this I don't think my understanding of this is correct.

Comment: The activation function of your hidden layer has little to do with whether the output layer outputs discrete or continuous values. The output layer of a neural network typically outputs continuous values which can then be discretized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually in the correct direction

**Option1:**

you need to normalize the temperatures first and then fed it to the model let say your temperature ranges from [-100,100] so convert it into a scale of [-1,1] then use this scaled version of temp in your target variable.

At the time of prediction just inverse transform the output and you will get your desired result.

**Option2:**

You create a regression kind of neural network and don't apply any activation function to the output layer (means no bonds for values it could be +ve or -ve).
In this case you are not required to normalize the values.

Sample NN Spec:

Input Layer==> # neurons one per feature

Hidden Layer==>relu/selu as activation function| # of neurons/Hidden layers is as per your requirement

Output Layer==> 1 neuron/ no Activation function required